# Type Of Authentication in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am a bit confused. I am looking for a good/explanatory answer about the type of authentication that i am using in my project.

So far i Know that asp.net follows 2 types of authentication -

1. **Windows Authentication**: Provides information on how to use Windows authentication in conjunction with Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) authentication to secure ASP.NET applications. (MSDN)
2. **Forms Authentication**: Provides information on how to create an application-specific login form and perform authentication using your own code. A convenient way to work with forms authentication is to use ASP.NET membership and ASP.NET login controls, which together provide a way to collect user credentials, authenticate them, and manage them, using little or no code. (MSDN)

But if some one is using sql server database and he has userid and passwords (encrypted) in a table and validating the user against the credentials supplied by him/her in Login Page against those table records then..my confusion is -

Am i using forms authentication with sql server validation..? In case if i am right.. :) then what is such authentication called..?

Please Help !!

Comment: in web.config see what type of authentication is used.

Comment: That's "Forms authentication". As the "Forms authentication" definition you pasted says: "...perform authentication using your own code.". You could have anything else besides SQL server like a XML file or any other database, that's simply the data repository you validate a user against.

Comment: @Jportelas Thanks for the confirmation

Answer (score 0):

i don't use Forms-Authentication myself but check this [Asp.Net Tutorial Link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs) to create the Membership Schema in SQL Server.

The whole [security chapter](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/security-basics-and-asp-net-support-cs) can provide useful information for you.

BR

Therak